# How to send "Ctrl+Q" event to other app when use QProcess launch it?

Tags: qt, qprocess

I have a app A. In A, have two button : Open and CLose.

- When I click Open button, it show other App - for example, name :B.
- **When I click Close button, my app send "CTRL+Q" event to close B app.**

I write code by Qt and VS2010. I use QProcess to show B. But I don't want to use QProcess::kill or close() to close B app. I want to send "CTRL+Q"event to close B app because I have some code in B app what free memory.
Thanks for helping!

P/s: In B App , I wrote if you press CTRL+Q , app close.

Resolve :
I don't find how to send "CTRL+Q" event but if you close other app, you should use "QProcess::terminate()". Don't use close or kill because it kill your other app.

Comment: B app is console application or GUI?

Comment: Sr. I found answer :D. I think it is not trouble. Thanks :D

Comment: Then please post your qnswer, perhaps it helps other people.

Comment: GUI applications on Windows, OS X and X 11 platforms can be terminated by sending them a platform-specific quit message (on X11 it's not called quit). This is done by `QProcess::terminate`. The `Ctrl-Q` shortcut is application-specific, you can't know if it might be language-specific, etc.